# Java - ClassCastException to the very same Class/Package

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to get the Class type received in a response and suddenly I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myweb.process.api.util.MyProcessModel 
cannot be cast to com.myweb.process.api.util.MyProcessModel
```

How is this possible?

Would this have something to do with the Classpath?

The code I am running is:

```
List<Object> responses = context.getResponses();
for (Object response : responses) {
   if (response instanceof MyProcessModel) {
      MyProcessModel model = (MyProcessModel) response;
      // Process...
   }
}
```

First, the `instanceof` is always `false` and if I try to cast the value it goes the exception above.

Comment: Possible if the two class instances came from different class loaders. Possible in Java EE environments.

Comment: @NicholasK Obviously, but the point is that it should enter the `IF` clause.

Comment: Can you perhaps describe your runtime?

Comment: @ernest_k I am not using Java-EE but Apache-Felix